# A box contains 10 balls, which are 6 W and 4 B. Assume you pick one by one, without replacement

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

What is the probability that only $1$ out of the first $4$ you picked are black?

So it is clear that we have picked $4$ balls. Our $4$ spots can be as follows:

$\mathrm{BWWW}$

$\mathrm{WBWW}$

$\mathrm{WWBW}$

$\mathrm{WWWB}$

$4$ ways to orient this.

There are $6$ W balls, from those we must pick $3$.

There are $4$ B balls, from those we must pick $1$.

Thus:

$$\frac{\displaystyle\binom{6}{3}\binom{4}{1}}{\displaystyle\binom{10}{4}}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, you interpret _"only 1 out of the first 4"_ as "1 and only 1 out of the first 4". A less likely meaning would be "at most 1 out of the first 4".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer is correct and is a good example of use of the [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution).